# Using command lines to take files

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am trying to open two files but for some reason the fopen keeps on returning Null. I am using codelite on mac. I have both of the files in the same folder and i have put the Files dictionary.txt and input.txt in the projects arguments in the settings. I also already tried using the full path and checked the reading permission of the files.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    FILE *dict;
    FILE *input;
    int x;

    if ( argc < 3 ) /* argc should be 3 for correct execution*/
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"1 or 2 Files were missing.");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( argc > 3 ){
        fprintf(stderr,"too many Arguments");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* We assume argv[1] and agrv[2] are filenames to open*/
    dict = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    input = fopen( argv[2], "r" );

    /* fopen returns NULL on failure */
    if ( dict == NULL ){
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file: %s\n", argv[1] );
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( input == NULL ){
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file: %s\n", argv[2] );
        exit(1);
    }
            /* Read one character at a time from file, stopping at EOF, which
                indicates the end of the file. Note that the idiom of "assign
                to a variable, check the value" used below works because
                the assignment statement evaluates to the value assigned. */
    while  ( ( x = fgetc( input ) ) != EOF ) {
                printf( "%c", x );
            }


    fclose( dict );
    fclose( input );

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Make sure the user running the program has read permission for the files, and also see if it works with the full path (maybe the program isn't being run from the directory you expect?)

Comment: I tried using the full path it still didnt work and i checked for read permission

Comment: You can use `void perror(const char *s);` instead of `fprintf` to show the detail error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re:

> I have both of the files in the same folder.

When working in an IDE, the folder you *think* you're in is oft not the folder you're *actually* in.

Put the following line temporarily at the start of `main()`:

```
system("pwd"); // UNIXy command to print working directory.
```

and see what it outputs. If it's different to where your files are, you need to either move them or change what you give your program on the command line.

---

Other things you may need to look out for are file permissions (you have to have read access) and file case (`Input.txt` is not the same as `input.txt`).

---

If none of those suggestions fix the problem, you can generally look at `errno` to see what the *specific* problem is. Include `errno'h` at the top of your code and print out the `errno` variable.

Or, in the `if` blocks that check for failure, change them to something like:

```
if ( dict == NULL ){
    fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file: %s\n", argv[1] );
    perror ("opening dict file");
    exit(1);
}
```